# Converting ASP.Net MVC to N-Tier

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-4, poco, n-tier-architecture

I recently started learning about ASP.Net MVC and its various features [MVC_3_MUSIC_STORE](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store-part-1) +
[CODE](http://mvcmusicstore.codeplex.com/) .
It looks very structured and simple to understand.

I was reading about enterprise applications and how they are layered/tiered in different sections
(logical/physical)

I was wondering(for learning ) how to do separate(convert) the above [MVC_3_MUSIC_STORE](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store-part-1) into  n-tier or 3 tier application (since we already have a working example) **in order to have a clean separation of concerns.**
I don't have much prior experience in this.

What changes would be required?

What will be different DTO(s) or POCO(s) that would be needed?
The above example uses POCO entities around from controller to views.
Would it remain same, assuming EF Code first is used.

Also i was wondering what changes will be required if WCF Webservice is introduced as a data access layer. i.e.Instead of retrieving data from DAL ,Clients will request data to and from WCF Webservice. Client can be Web app or WinForms or Sliverlight app.
( **[DAL** <--> **WCF WS]** <--> **N CLIENTS**)

Would be interesting to know about various approaches.

Example code would be helpful and/or examples for same.

**Edit 1 - Added**
One of the things I noticed was when i move the model classes from Model folder to new project "MYMODEL" I will have to again add reference to "System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations" and "System.Web.Mvc" in new model project?

How can this be avoided? How can these validations be moved to Business layer?

[image: References will be lost if moved to new project]

**Edit 2**
Looking for something similar to this 
[Advice For A Newbie About N-Tier Applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4484081/advice-for-a-newbie-about-n-tier-applications)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally the only change that will be required is that you will provide an implementation of the repository (DAL layer) which will call a WCF web service to fetch the domain models from instead of some EF DataContext talking directly to the database. A change completely transparent to Controllers and Views.

Comment: That doesn't "make it N-tier", that makes it service oriented (which is in itself an overloaded term).  UI layer + business layer + data storage layer = 3-tier architecture.  Nothing in that mandates web services.

Comment: @Eric J., while I am really not familiar with the terms, that's definitely how I would do it.

Comment: Based on what requirement set?  WCF is slow compared to direct database access (it's also slow compared to a native HTTP handler).  There's value in many cases to exposing functionality via web services, but there's also a cost.  Applying a solution without questioning the problem leads to bad architecture choices.  Our solution can process billions of requests per day, and would take almost double the hardware if we introduced WCF as an additional layer.  For the definition of the terms see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitier_architecture

Comment: @Eric J., I never mentioned anything about performance, I am just answering the OP question which I remind you is: What would be the proper way to invoke a WCF service from an ASP.NET MVC application.

Comment: @Darin : Added some more info to the question

Comment: @Eric J. - I think you're confused.  3 layers doesn't make it 3-tier.  Layers are abstractions, tiers are physical seperations.  Still, the point is the question asker asked specifically about how to abstract the data layer into n-tiers, and asked specifically about how to replace data access with service access.  Also, a web  service is a physical seperation and qualifies as a tier.

Comment: @Amitd, you could reference `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` in your business tier in order to perform validation on your models. On the other hand you should not reference `System.Web.Mvc`. Any validation attributes that are in this assembly are tied to ASP.NET MVC and should not be used on your models but on your view models which reside in the Web tier.

Comment: @Darin does that mean I would need to have a separate model for Business tier and separate model for Web Tier? and again do the mapping at time of passing them on to Web tier? Is it possible to re-use the POCO created in Web Tier above? (classes for EF i meant)

Comment: @Amitd, yes, it is a good practice to have view models in your web tier which are specifically designed for the requirements of the view.